# Give the ability to only edit tags for a question without the editing post (Body)

Tags: feature-request, tags, edits

#### Question edit problem when I am only editing tags

Recently I tried to add a tag for a question, but it gave the error

> Edits must be at least 6 characters; is there something else to improve in this post?

*Personal opinion*: I think it’s not necessary to add at least six characters to improve a post when I add a missing tag for a question...

**Edit Problem Picture**

[image]

**Edit Question**

[image]

Comment: Such an exemption actually exists, and works for most posts. You just happened to hit one of the few that doesn't. See the FAQ [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work), subsection *I'm not modifying the post body, but I'm still receiving an error about needing to change six characters. What gives?*.

Comment: @Sonic the Curiouser Hedgehog _Give ability to only edit tag for a question without editing post (Body)_ . It's feature request ...

Comment: Why not removing the _(talking about using msfvenom fyi)_ completely after adding that information as tag?

Comment: @honk i write about it _I think it’s not necessary to add at least 6 characters to improve post when I add missing tag for question._

Comment: As I said, this feature *already exists*: if you edit the tags without editing the body, the system is programmed to allow the edit. However, on *some specific* posts you'll *mistakenly* get the error message, for the reasons outlined in the FAQ post I linked. That bug has already been reported, which is the other target that Glorfindel added to this question.

Comment: The first orig is not a feature request, but a bug report. It could be fixed by suggesting a re-tagging ;-) The second orig is a general description, how suggested edits work. I think we should either retag the first as feature-request, or vote this to reopen. I did the second, as the change would be too much (it is clearly formulated as bug report).

Comment: @noor I think this post would be better as a feature-request, please consider to tag it as so. If it is bugreport, or support, then it is a dupe.